# Сортировка строк в файле по числу после разделителя

Tags: linux, bash, сортировка

У меня есть файл `high.txt` в нём записано такое:

```
vova:14
dimdim:64
vova:66
player:246
pepe:2
pepe:35
```

Вопрос в том как отсортировать этот файл по числу после `:`, должно получиться такое:

```
player:246
vova:66
dimdim:64
pepe:35
vova:14
pepe:2
```

Используя команду `sort -th -n` идёт сортировка по алфавиту.
Может, используя регулярные выражения это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разобрался, вот команда для сортировки: `sort -nr -t : -k 2,2 high.txt`

> -n операции с числами
>
> -r перевернуть файл
>
> -t указать разделитель
>
> -k номер столбца